# PowerShell Search and Replace yaml

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some solution to this Problem Statement please

Let say we have two files, one is in yaml format and have specific placeholder, for ex - (member_name). Please note, since the file format is in yaml it will have certain amount of blank spaces before the placeholder.

Then we have a separate file that has the actual name of the member in this format – member_name: abc xyz. This file does not have additional spaces.

What I need is, to replace the content of yaml file, placeholder, without disturbing the file structure, with the corresponding values from the second file.

Like the yaml file after execution should have member_name: abc xyz, along with the spaces in the original file.

This has to go in loop since I have multiple placeholders in the file A and corresponding values in the second file.

Let me know if I am not clear please.

This is what I have tried out...

```
$realmember = GC "\Path\to\file\realMember.txt"
$yamlfile = GC "\Path\to\file\yamlFile"

foreach($line in $yamlfile){

    $script:found += @($line | select-string -Pattern '(*)$' | %{$_ -replace '(\s*','*'} | %{$_ -replace ')','*'})
}

for($i = 0; $i -lt ($realMember.Count); $i++){

    if($realMember[$i] -like $found[$i].Trim()){

        $secrets = $realMember[$i]

        $file = $file -replace "[^\s*].*[^\s*]<*>$","$realMember[$i]" #| Where-Object {$_ -match "$realMember[$i]"}

    }

}

$file
```

but this prints result in following format, all values in each of the field. I need to find out if there is a way to include variables with regex while replacing OR any other better ways to achieve this

```
MemberData:
  member_id: 01
  member_name_1: abc def member_name_2: ghi jkl member_name_3: mno pqr member_name_4: stu vwx[x]
  member_id: 02
  member_name_1: abc def member_name_2: ghi jkl member_name_3: mno pqr member_name_4: stu vwx[x]
  new_members:
    member_id: 003
    member_name_1: abc def member_name_2: ghi jkl member_name_3: mno pqr member_name_4: stu vwx[x]
    member_id: 004
    member_name_1: abc def member_name_2: ghi jkl member_name_3: mno pqr member_name_4: stu vwx[x]
```

===========================

**realMember.txt content**

```
member_name_1: abc def
member_name_2: ghi jkl
member_name_3: mno pqr
member_name_4: stu vwx
```

===========================

**yamlFile content**

```
MemberData:
  member_id: 01
  (member_name_1)
  member_id: 02
  (member_name_2)
  new_members:
   member_id: 003
   (member_name_3)
   member_id: 004
   (member_name_4)
```

Comment: Where's the error in your current attempt?

Comment: Hello, I have given the code snippet that I have tried out, and the related issue. There isn't any error but it is replacing the placeholders with all the tokens in a single line. What I am looking for here is that it will replace the placeholder with the exact token match only. Please HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone looking for the solution can see it here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/770bc9a4-6100-4825-8b10-dc76363cc44c/powershell-search-and-replace-yaml?forum=ITCG